# Display WooCommerce newest product reviews on top

Tags: filters, woocommerce-offtopic

By default, woocommerce product reviews are listed in chronological order. How do you get the newest review to appear first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I couldn't find this documented anywhere, but the solution is pretty simple.

In `single_product_review.php`, the arguments passed to [wp_list_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) are filtered:

`wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ) );`

by adding `reverse_top_level` to the arguments, the order is reversed.

Add the following code to your theme's functions.php:

```
// show newest product reviews on top
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', 'newest_reviews_first' );
function newest_reviews_first($args) {
    $args['reverse_top_level'] = true;
    return $args;
}
```